# Detect when scanf got no input

Tags: c, scanf

I'm new to C and couldn't have the answer after some research.

I have a while loop that I want to terminate if I input nothing (hit enter) to scanf(). The below doesn't work...

```
int data;
while(1){
    scanf("%d", &data);
    if data == NULL{
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf` instead.

Comment: You cannot enter "nothing".  You could enter no text other than an <enter> - which means you input a `\n`.  You could _close_ `stdin`.  But simple entering "nothing" (typing no keys), your I/O interface (keyboard) normally simple waits for the user to enter "something".

Comment: If you want to e.g. timeout the reading wait, you'll need some operating system specific multiplexing stuff like, on Posix & Linux systems, [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). In that case, edit your question to tell which OS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fgets()/sscanf()`

```
int data;
char buf[40];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &data) != 1) break;
  // do stuff with data
}
```

Comment: @OP When a `\n` is entered with `scanf("%d", ...)`, the function simple consumes it (plus any white-space) until a non-white-space occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Use the return value from [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf):

```
int data;
while (1) {
    int n = scanf("%d", &data);
    if (n != 1)
        break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tried your code and it did not stop on an input of nothing (e.g. a lone `\n`).  `scanf("%d",...` simple eats the lone `\n` as `%d` consumes leading white-space and does not return until a non-white space is entered.